# Highlight specific substrings in a QTreeView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, highlight, qtreeview

I want to highlight (or in general customise the formatting) of specific substrings appearing in a QTreeView in PyQt. To demonstrate what I mean, I have taken the example at `PyQt4\examples\itemviews\dirview.pyw` and manually added highlighting:

[image]

Here all instances of the substring 'as' are highlighted, but in general it might not be a pattern match, I may actually want to be very specific.

I know that this can be easily done to a QTextEdit as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981824/how-can-i-find-a-substring-and-highlight-it-in-qtextedit), but that relied on moving around the `textCursor` which I don't believe exists for a QTreeView.

Can this be easily done?

Comment: You need to use a delegate to display the text in your treeview. With a delegate you can define your own widget (containing a label, lineedit, etc.) displaying (and formatting) the data received from the model. Have a look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes

Comment: There is ready solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5443112/1387438