# QtWidgets.QTextEdit.textCursor().movePosition(); how to define the exact number of characters?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit

A method to find a substring and highlight it in QTextEdit [has already been proposed in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13988652/4391360) by [vicent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562213/vicent).

This is an elegant and effective method. However as it is used:

```
cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.EndOfWord, 1)
```

the highlighting goes to the end of the word where the substring is detected.

I am looking for a way to define the exact number of characters. Something like this (doesn't work!):

```
cursor.movePosition(len(pattern), 1)
```

to highlight only the substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for-loop with `QTextCursor::Right`:

```py
for _ in pattern:
    cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.Right, 1)
```

Comment: exactly what I needed!